# Convert Swagger Api to Asciidoc

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, asciidoc

I need to convert my swagger.json file to asciidoc.
I'm using this well-known package special for this task - https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup-cli

So when I convert my swagger I haven't got my paths(GET, POST requests).
My output:

```
DEBUG i.g.s.i.document.PathsDocument - Generate examples is disabled.
15:42:49.766 [main] DEBUG i.g.s.i.document.PathsDocument - Create separated operation files is disabled.
15:42:49.768 [main] DEBUG i.g.s.i.document.DefinitionsDocument - Create separated definition files is disabled.
```

My swagger.json file:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "description": "Сервер позволяет переводить текст с одного языка на язык",
        "title": "Переводчик",
        "contact": {},
        "version": "2.0"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/api/v1/langlist": {
            "get": {
                "consumes": [
                    "*/*"
                ],
                "produces": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "tags": [
                    "API"
                ],
                "summary": "Получить список доступных языков",
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "OK",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "additionalProperties": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/api/v1/translate/:from/:to": {
            "post": {
                "consumes": [
                    "*/*"
                ],
                "produces": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "tags": [
                    "API"
                ],
                "summary": "Получить список доступных языков",
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "OK",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "additionalProperties": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: What is the question here exactly?

Comment: @Helen, added the question

Comment: Can you post your swagger.json file so that others can reproduce the issue? Also make sure your swagger.json is valid, e.g. paste it into https://editor.swagger.io and make sure there are no errors.

Comment: @Helen, thanks for advice. Just did it.